# How to determine when to update deviceToken for push notifications / how to get it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, remote-notifications

I've had various struggles with push notifications over the course of my app that seem to be fixed by uninstalling. I believe I've narrowed it down to expired deviceTokens.

Reading [Apple's Push notification documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html), I found this:

> Registration Succeeded But No Notifications Received
>
> . . .
>
> Your app may have sent an incorrect device token to your provider.
>   Your app should always ask for the device token by registering with
>   the push service each time it is launched. Don't store a device token
>   from your app and try to reuse it, because the token can change. Your
>   provider should then pass that same token on to the push service.

They suggest registering each time the app is launched. They also suggest best practice for push notifications is not to do that, since users don't like getting bombarded with access requests before even getting to see your app. So, just throwing the registration call into the app delegate isn't the best option. However, I am not seeing any more info on when a deviceToken expires or how to see if it has expired.

The closest thing I can find is [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications) on `UIApplication`'s instance method `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`:

> **Return** Value YES if the app is registered for remote notifications and
>   received its device token or NO if registration has not occurred, has
>   failed, or has been denied by the user.

My understanding is that this is the method to call to check if a user has enabled push notification services. I understand that permissions for specific notification types could all be turned off and this could still be true if the user allows push notifications. But the wording looks like it requires the app to be registered with the current deviceToken.  Does this mean that I could call

```
[[UIApplication currentApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```

inside the appDelegate, and if it's true, register remote notifications to update my deviceToken on my server and make sure my push notifications don't expire? Or, is this function going to run into the same thing that I currently am, where eventually the deviceToken is going to expire and this method will begin to return false instead of true, even though the user had allowed push notification?

tl;dr - Apple says deviceTokens eventually expire for push notifications. They suggest registering every time the app launches. I don't want to bombard new users with that alert. How do I ensure only users who have already accepted push notifications get re-registered?

Answer (score 0):

The alert will only be shown once.

If the user previously Allowed notifications, your code will get the new token without needing any interaction from (or UI notice to) the user.

Comment: In the `application didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` method, I handle updating the deviceToken on my server, but that seems to not be working, as I have a lot of users with outdated tokens.

The alert only being shown once is why I don't want to just throw the registration method right in the launch process. I want to wait until the appropriate time in my app, so I can display a relevant message including why we want to use push notifications, and use our own prompt before the official Apple prompt, so we don't waste it if they're gonna say no. This is a best practice recommended by Apple.

Comment: That being said, you're saying the device will know the token was updated still, so if I check that `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` boolean, and it's true, I should be all set?

Comment: As I understand it, yes... `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` should return the correct value. So you can wait until you are ready to prompt, check the value of `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`... if it's TRUE, call `registerForRemoteNotifications` to *silently* check for / get a new Token... if it's FALSE, show your own prompt, then call `registerForRemoteNotifications` (or not) as desired.

Comment: @DonMag  More importantly, what happens to the user topic subscriptions when the device token changes?  When I detect a token change, do I have to un-subscribe the users original token from all the topics they were subscribed to and then re-register the user for all the same topics using the new token?  Or is this somehow auto-managed in the background - FCM auto removes bad tokens and reassigns new tokens for all the user subscribed topics?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the best practice for this are as follows, which we follow without failure

1. Always **register** for the Push on app launch, or in suitable AppDelegate lifecycle methods, using the following code

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:  [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil]];

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   ```
2. The delegate for Push if it is successfully registered will get called with deviceToken

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
   ```

   The delegate above will get called if there is change in deviceToken always. So whenever you get a deviceToken update it in the server.
3. In the server make sure you hit correct mode if you are running in **Sandbox, or Production** mode, discard values from Simulators they normally fails and block the service for sometime.

You can always check with your pem file and device token that Push is working or not with [this online service](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/).

Hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @iphonic, but I don't want to blast the registration on launch for new users. This is not recommended by Apple. They suggest themselves wrapping this in your own prompt explaining why you want to use push notifications, and displaying that at a relevant time. Then, only display the official prompt if the user shows interest in accepting, so you don't waste the system prompt.

That's why I want a way of only calling the register method if the user has already accepted, and am looking for confirmation that `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` will always be Yes if the user accepted,

Comment: @JakeT. You don't need to do it on launch until the user has allowed for Push, and once the user allowed for Push the alert won't prompt it silently generates Device Token when you call register the second time, and your server call is only triggered when device token has been fetched.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to do. If I call registerForRemoteNotifications before the user has accepted, it's going to prompt them, so 1) in your list is going to trigger that prompt, and I don't want to do that. I want to only call `registerForRemoteNotifications` for users who have already accepted, and am trying to ensure the method I outlined is reliable, and am looking for confirmation.

Comment: @JakeT. Prompt for Push comes only once whether you accept or, reject, however if you reject user can enable it from Device Settings for the app. But you can't skip the prompt even once that's required. Calling register multiple times won't trigger multiple prompts.

Comment: Yes. Again, that's why I don't want to throw a blanket register call right inside the app delegate at launch as you suggested. But, I want to make sure I have an updated deviceToken on my server, which currently isn't happening by only ever calling registerForRemoteNotifications the one time. So I want to call it again only for users who have already accepted, so I can make sure I have an up to date token on my server. The question is about reliably checking they have accepted notifications so I know to call the register method again.